# ArgumentOutOfRangeException when sorting DataGridView

Tags: c#, datatable, sqlite, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to sort DGV by column with this code:

```
points.Clear();
foreach ( CalibrationPoint pt in ch.SWCalibration.Points )
    points.Add( pt );
if ( points.Count > 0 )
    this.dgv.Sort( this.dgv.Columns[ 'X' ], ListSortDirection.Ascending );
```

where `points` is a `SortableBindingList`, bound to DGV

When i call `Sort` method, i get **ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index**

here is stack trace output:

```
System.Collections.ArrayList.get_Item(Int32 index)
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
...
```

below is my function call, with sort posted above and the rest of function calls.

do you know why this happens? i checked, when points.Count > 0, dgv.Rows.Count also is > 0, i.e. rows are added with each point added to the list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strangely this line compiles

```
this.dgv.Sort( this.dgv.Columns[ 'X' ], ListSortDirection.Ascending );
```

Strangely because the indexer of the [DataGridViewColumnCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts a 32 bit integer that represent the index of the column or a string with the name of the column.

What happens here is the automatic conversion of a char to an int.
So your code is referencing the column with index 88 (the ascii value of X) and of course there is no column with such high index.
To fix this error use the correct index number or use the name of the column.
For example

```
this.dgv.Sort( this.dgv.Columns["ColumnName"], ListSortDirection.Ascending );
```

Comment: Like I wrote in a comment to asfaloth.arwen, i really didn't have column of that name, but only with that header name. I actually had 2 errors in my code: 1. wrong name, 2. char instead of string, thanks for your answer as well

Answer (score 1):

this.dgv.Columns probably does not contain 'X'. Make sure you specify the column correctly by name or index. See [Columns property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: You're right, I was sure I have this column, but I checked ... i have "colX" column with "X" header. This solves my problem I'll accept answer when I'll be able to. ... so dumb problem